# Solving the IVP $ty''-ty'+y=1$ where $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0)=2$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

> Solving the IVP 
>   $$ty''-ty'+y=1$$
>   where $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0)=2$.

I'm struggling to get started. I've solved some problems of similar fashion, but without the t factor on the left hand side.

Comment: the solution containes the exponential integral

Comment: May I ask where this problem comes from?

Comment: It's from an advanced math course exercise at my university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ty''-ty'+y=1$$
$$-\left(s^2{\cal L}(y)-sy(0)-y'(0)\right)'+\left(s{\cal L}(y)-y(0)\right)'+{\cal L}(y)=\dfrac{1}{s}$$
$$(s-s^2){\cal L}'(y)+(2-2s){\cal L}(y)=\dfrac{1}{s}$$
$${\cal L}'(y)+\dfrac2s{\cal L}(y)=\dfrac{1}{s^2(1-s)}$$
with integrating factor $s^2$ we have
\begin{align}
(s^2{\cal L}(y))'
&= \dfrac{1}{1-s} \\
y&={\cal L}^{-1}\dfrac{-\ln(1-s)}{s^2}+Ct \\
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{e^x}{x}(t-x)dx+Ct \\
&= t\int_0^t\dfrac{e^x}{x}dx-e^t+1+Ct \\
&= t\operatorname{Ei}(t)-e^t+1+Ct 
\end{align}